# error accessing simple array

Tags: java, arrays

Have an ArrayList the first element is a simple String[][], the rest are ArrayLists.  I need to retrieve and parse that array.  I can get the first structure into a list as below

```
Object o = results.get(0);
List l = Arrays.asList(o);
```

However when I try the following I get the error in the third below

```
int len = ((String[])l.get(tokenInd)).length; or
int len = ((ArrayList)l.get(tokenInd)).size();
```

I get 
java.lang.ClassCastException: [[Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two '[' in the front indicate that this is a two-dimensional array, and you are trying to cast it to a one-dimensional one.  Try:

```
int len = ((String[][])l.get(tokenInd)).length;
```

Comment: TY.  Obvious but I thought I already had the first dimension and needed to cast the vector.